# Take out one div from its class

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working with Javascript and HTML, and I have several div-tags with the same class.

```
<div class="box"> Hello </div>
<div class="box"> How are you? </div>
<div class="box"> Goodbye </div>
<div class="box"> Who are you? </div>
```

Then I have a a-tag FOR EACH DIV:

```
<a> Click me </a>
```

So it will be like this:

```
<div class="box"> Hello </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> How are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Goodbye </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Who are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>
```

My question is: How do I get the value of a div if I click on its a-tag? (with Javascript)

Comment: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) + [`.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)

Comment: Please also post what you have tried here.

Comment: can you show us your code, so we can help :

Comment: How do I get the .previousElementSibling when I have several a-tags?

Answer (score 0):

**You can write simple jquery code here the code:**

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).prev().text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"> Hello </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> How are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Goodbye </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Who are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>
```

Comment: _"(with Javascript)"_

Comment: How do I get the .previousElementSibling when I have several a-tags?

Comment: You needed more and more learn about javascript, 
I hope you needed a hire a developer

Comment: @LMinor you can find attach a click handler in a and find siblings it's simple

Comment: I don't understand you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas. I didn't know about `.previousElementSibling`.

```
var getValueOfDiv = void 0;
{
    getValueOfDiv = function () {
        console.log(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
        return false;
    }
}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('a'), 
    function (element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', getValueOfDiv, false);
    }
);
```

Comment: what is `e` here? (I know what you intended or can guess but it is NOT defined) and `target.parentNode` does not exist (well it does but it is not the div`

Comment: `e = e || window.event;` but I think I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is not a propper way to do it. probably what you want to do this

```js
var link = document.getElementById('abc');
       abc.addEventListener('click',function(e){
           if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'){
               
             console.log(e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML);
            }
        
          
       });
```

```html
<div id="abc">
            <div class="box"> Hello </div>
            <a> Click me </a>
            
            <div class="box"> How are you? </div>
            <a> Click me </a>
            
            <div class="box"> Goodbye </div>
            <a> Click me </a>
            
            <div class="box"> Who are you? </div>
            <a> Click me </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok but if I have <div class="abc"> ?

Comment: something like this document.getElementsByclassName('abc')[0]; to select the first element that have this class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `previousElementSibling` like this

```
function clickATag(){
   let sib = this.previousElementSibling;
   sib.style.border = "1px solid red"
   console.log(sib.innerText);
}
```

```js
function clickATag(){
   let sib = this.previousElementSibling;
   sib.style.border = "1px solid red";
   console.log(sib.innerText)
  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('a'), 
    function (element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', clickATag, false);
    }
);
```

```html
<div class="box"> Hello </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> How are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Goodbye </div>
<a> Click me </a>

<div class="box"> Who are you? </div>
<a> Click me </a>
```